# What is the goal of module.exports in webpack.config.js?

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundle, webpack.config.js

We are not importing this object anywhere so I am wondering why do we export it ?

Thank you for your willingness to help !

Answer (score 0):

Well, webpack needs to import it so...